# Any $K$-homomorphism is an automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $F/K$ be an algebraic extension.Then any $K$-homomorphism from $F$ to $F$ is an automorphism.

Clearly the $K$-homomorphism is one to one as it is defined from a field to a field.So the only requirement is to show that it onto.

Any insight.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The image of the homomorphism is a subspace of the finite-dimensional $K$-vector space $F$. (I'm assuming $F/K$ is not just algebraic but actually finite, since that's often the convention for intro Galois theory; is that the case? Otherwise, the same argument works with a bit more care.)

Comment: I don't think so,it is only algebraic,it may be infinite..

Comment: In that case, note that for arbitrary $x\in K$, there exists a finite extension $L/F$ fixed by the homomorphism that contains $x$.

Comment: Sorry ,but I didn't get you , how we find a finite extension $L$ ?

Comment: Use the fact that $x$ is algebraic. It's pretty much the same argument as in @ZhiyuZhang's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be in F with minimal polynomial
f, and S is the set containing all conjugations of a in F (there are only finite many of them as they are all roots of f). Now the morphism preserves S and is injective hence must be surjective on S as it's finite. So $a$ lies in the image hence it's onto.

Comment: What do you mean by conjugation of $a$ ?

Comment: @HirenGarai The roots of f in F

Comment: One last clarification needed I hope, how $ a$ lies in the image of F under the homomorphism ? Is it because the image of S under the homomorphism (which is S itself) is a subset of the image of F under the homomorphism ?

Comment: @HirenGarai The homomorphism sends S to S. Now an injective map from S to S must be surjective because S is finite, hence S lies in the image. At last, note a lies in S

Comment: Yess ! And S is a subset of Image Of F ,so $a$ lies in the image of F , am I getting right ?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Ok ! I get it now.. Thanks for the answer ..